# How do I proxy nginx correct?

Tags: nginx, proxy, reverse-proxy

// EDIT: it is my local development server

I have PHP built-in server running on port 8000 for host `somehost.dev`.
I want nginx to proxy `somehost.dev` from 80 port to 8000.
My config:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name *.dev;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header   Host             $host;
        proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

        proxy_pass http://$host:8000$uri;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }
}
```

Getting error:

```
[error] 30106#0: *1 no resolver defined to resolve somehost.dev, client: 127.0.0.1, server: *.dev, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", host: "somehost.dev", referrer: "http://somehost.dev/admin"
```

What I do wrong?

Comment: [Be careful](http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php). `Warning: This web server was designed to aid application development. It may also be useful for testing purposes or for application demonstrations that are run in controlled environments. It is not intended to be a full-featured web server. It should not be used on a public network.` In other words, this is almost certainly a bad idea.

Comment: I know what I do. It's on local development server.

Comment: If you know what you do, then have you tried Googling the error you got? Literally the [first](http://www.nginx-discovery.com/2011/05/day-51-proxypass-and-resolver.html) result for a search of 'no resolver defined to resolve' tells you you might need to set a [resolver](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#resolver)

Answer (score 3):

Add `resolver 127.0.0.1;` to your config, replacing 127.0.0.1 with your DNS server(s) in your setup if you are not running DNS locally.

---

**Nginx Resolver Info:**

```
Syntax: resolver address ... [valid=time] [ipv6=on|off];
Default: —
Context: http, server, location
```

Configures name servers used to resolve names of upstream servers into addresses, for example:

```
resolver 127.0.0.1 [::1]:5353;
```

An address can be specified as a domain name or IP address, and an optional port (1.3.1, 1.2.2). If port is not specified, the port 53 is used. Name servers are queried in a round-robin fashion.

> Before version 1.1.7, only a single name server could be configured.
>   Specifying name servers using IPv6 addresses is supported starting
>   from versions 1.3.1 and 1.2.2.

By default, nginx will look up both IPv4 and IPv6 addresses while resolving. If looking up of IPv6 addresses is not desired, the ipv6=off parameter can be specified.

> Resolving of names into IPv6 addresses is supported starting from
>   version 1.5.8.

By default, nginx caches answers using the TTL value of a response. An optional `valid` parameter allows overriding it:

```
resolver 127.0.0.1 [::1]:5353 valid=30s;
```

> Before version 1.1.9, tuning of caching time was not possible, and
>   nginx always cached answers for the duration of 5 minutes.

```
Syntax: resolver_timeout time;
Default: resolver_timeout 30s;
Context: http, server, location
```

Sets a timeout for name resolution, for example:

```
resolver_timeout 5s;
```

Comment: Won't there need to be a DNS resolver at 127.0.0.1 for that to work? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8305015/when-using-proxy-pass-can-etc-hosts-be-used-to-resolve-domain-names-instead-of indicates you'd need something like `dnsmasq` for this.